# Estimating the common underlying process of a sample of time series

Tags: time-series, sample

Often, time series analysis is based on a single series. However, this is not always the case.

Let's assume that we have a sample of time series related to the same phenomenon, with equal frequency. I am wondering if it could be statistically meaningful:

1. to calculate the sample distribution of the mean;
2. recompose a time series where each point is the sample average of that point;

in order to build the "average" series, considering it as the “general model” of the series.

Then, based on that, to calculate which realization of the series (the concrete series in the dataset) are closer or significantly different from that average.

Since I am not a statistician, I'd like to hear from someone more expert than me if this line of reasoning is wrong, or reasonable, or can be somehow improved? Any hints are very appreciated

Comment: You don't "employ bootstrapping to approximate the distribution of the population based on the Central Limit Theorem." The CLT estimates the sampling distribution *of the mean*, and bootstrapping of whatever statistic you are estimating (mean or otherwise). Precisely CLT is a limit theorem that doesn't require resampling techniques like bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very useful! I edited the question!

Comment: Provided you have enough such series and you suppose they are independent of each other and have the same marginal distributions, there's nothing wrong with using these data to estimate the characteristics of the common underlying process.  As noted by @AdamO, though, the CLT is not going to play any role in this.  That makes your title misleading.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, I’ll look into it! I also edit the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem description correctly, it's easiest to summarize with a relatable example. Suppose you place several weather monitoring stations at various locations within a city and collected monthly data over several years and your goal is to summarize the climate of *the city* (rainfall, temperature, etc.). For simplicity we are assuming the various stations are independent (for more detailed methods, look into universal kriging).

There is nothing too complicated to summarizing simple cross-sectional data. You can report the average December temperature as the average of December temperature over all stations and over all years. Going farther, you can assess the alignment of various sites or years by considering the root-mean-squared error of the series against the average, or any other adequate norm, (such as $\mathcal{L}_{\inf}$ norm which, in other words, measures the maximal deviation from a particular series from the average). This method relies on the data being collected at regular intervals. If irregular, other methods may be used (but it's a different question, IMO).

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a very clear and good answer!